# What's the meaning of ないでくれないかなあ？

Tags: grammar

I studied that when there is a verb in negative form plus かなあ it means "I desire that", like in: 早く始まらないかなあ。

But, I came across this sentence: "見ないでくれないかなあ", which apparently means "I don't want you to see it". The problem is that I don't understand all these negative forms one after another, could somebody shed more light on this matter?

Answer (score 2):

> 見ないでくれないかなあ

means:

> Would you mind not looking?

In parts:

- 見ないで "not look" (i.e. "refrain from looking")
- くれない "wouldn't you" (do it for me)
- かなあ makes it a question; something akin to "I wonder if"

Comment: In this case, I would say that かなあ functions more as a 'softener', making it more like a polite request rather than an actual question.

Comment: @kandyman This is what I meant by giving an example "I wonder if" and the translation "would you mind" - these expressions act as softeners in English, don't they? The former uses a question-form in the relative clause, the latter turns the form of the whole English sentence into a question, although neither does demand an answer. So I don't think it is a mistake to claim か（なあ） works similarly.

Comment: @Kasumi, whether those act as softeners or not in English I think is largely dependent on the intonation you use. I can imagine "Would you mind not looking?", sounding extremely curt, just like plain 見ないでくれないかな？would tend to sound.